# How to copy a column but only copy variables with "<" Symbol and change the rest to NA

Tags: r

I have a dataset with concentrations. Some of them are labeled with a "<" symbol.
I want to copy the column with the concentration but only the variables with "<" symbol in it. all others should be changed to "NA".

my code looks like this:
raw_data$new_column <- ifelse(grepl("<", raw_data$Messwert, **Value**, "NA"))

obviously **Value** doesn`t work. But i can`t figure it out, I`m new to programming and would appreciate your help a lot.  How should i solve this Problem?

my data set should look like this:

| ID | Concentration | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.134 | NA |
| 2 | <0.01 | <0.01 |
| 3 | 0.32 | NA |
| 4 | <0.0005 | <0.0005 |
| 5 | 0.75 | NA |

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use

```
raw_data$new_column <- ifelse(grepl("<", raw_data$Concentration),
     raw_data$Concentration, NA)
```

-output

```
> raw_data
  ID Concentration new_column
1  1         0.134       <NA>
2  2         <0.01      <0.01
3  3          0.32       <NA>
4  4       <0.0005    <0.0005
5  5          0.75       <NA>
```

#### data

```
raw_data <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Concentration = c("0.134", "<0.01", 
"0.32", "<0.0005", "0.75")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ifelse needs a conditional argument first, try something like this

```
ifelse(grepl("<", raw_data$Concentration) == TRUE, raw_data$Concentration, "NA"))
```